# LWC not displaying any data

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have one LWC component, which displays the list of Contacts.
But its not displaying any data in the component. from debug log I can see my apex controller is returning data, but not sure why it is not getting displayed.
I have taken the code from the lwc-recipes
HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card
        title="Apex Wire Method">
        <template if:true={contacts.data}>
            <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.name}</p>
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

js:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContactList';

export default class ApexWireMetodToSalesforce extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getContactList) contacts;


}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class ContactController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContactList() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Phone, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 100];
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please expose your apex controller? maybe you have missed querying name field?

Comment: are you sure you have saved and deployed every file (html, js, apex)?

Comment: also, can you add code `<template if:true={contacts.error}>{contacts.error}</template> to display any errors?

Comment: I have added apex controller in my question, yes every file is deployed in sfdc and I have added error condition but still its facing the issue

Comment: do you see any errors either in Javascript console, UI or Apex Logs? Could you please provide screenshot of what you are seeing and how do you detect that Apex is returning data? probably there are no contacts in your org

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve, just by changing the **name** to **Name** in

```
<template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.name}</p>
            </template>
```